# How knows JVM the generics type paramter without arguments?

Tags: java, generics

I have a generics factory method.

```
public static <T> List<T> create(){
    return new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

But it hasn't arguments/parameters.

I don't give the type paramter for the function, but it knows the appropriate type without any arguments.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    List<Integer> intlist = create();  //it is an Integer List
    List<String> stringlist = create();  //it is a String List
}
```

Comment: It's inferred from the left side of the declaration.

Comment: This is probably one of the few not completely useless cases where a generic parameter used only once in a method signature makes sense. (Albeit not much with the diamond operator present in Java 7.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JVM doesn't know the generic type parameter due to type erasure.

The Java compiler is able to infer that `T` should be `Integer` or `String` in your examples, because it has access to the generic type information on the types of the variables you have declared.

Comment: So for the JVM is it 'List intlist = new ArrayList;' in both cases (Integer, String) due to type erasure?

Comment: @user2693979 For the JVM they're just `List` and `ArrayList`, the latter of which holds an `Object[]`. Type erasure means generic type information is not implicitly attached to *instances*. (You can still attach it explicitly by passing around `Class` objects, and the information is preserved in type and method declarations accessible over reflection.)

Answer (score 1):

One point of view is that when the generic parameter is not explicitly given, it is inferred. Usually, it is inferred from the arguments, but when there are no arguments, in limited cases (e.g. variable declaration) it can be inferred from the left side.

Another point of view is that, when the generic parameter is not explicitly given, the compiler *doesn't really care* what the parameter is exactly. After all, the type parameter does not affect the compiled bytecode at all. It just needs to be able to prove that *there exists some type parameter* that would make it work; and it doesn't care any more. There could be multiple valid type parameters for a situation; but it doesn't care which one is "used", because it has no effect on the result. In this case, since the method takes no arguments and returns a `List<T>` where `T` is a generic for the method, as long as it's used in a context that takes a `List`, it is valid, because regardless of `List<what exactly>` is desired, a valid `T` exists (`T` = `whatever type parameter is desired`). So the compiler doesn't actually need to check the type parameter at all in this case.